# print size of ".pdf" is not same as in ".ai"

Tags: pdf, printing, size, adobe-illustrator

[this is the .pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jNLMY15v1rcG9zMVhtRWE0UTA/view?usp=sharing)

Hi, I created this image in illustrator, with A4 size and with exact scale measurement, and saved it to .pdf format.
Now I printed this pdf file, but the size is not exact in the print. (3mm is missing).Iam trying this for past three days,but not working.
Can anybody help?

[.pictire of printed pdf in A4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCQZN.png)

Comment: how do you print? Some PDF printing software considers (optionally) non printable margin areas and scales down the PDF to fit inside.

Comment: I printed the pdf file using 'adobe acrobat' software, and also I tried opening the pdf in browser(chrome) and printed it

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Reader one can use the *measure* tool to verify that the dimensions still are correct. Thus, the problem occurs during printing.

When I tried to print your PDF the unmodified print dialog looked like this for me:

[image: Screenshot]

In particular the option "Shrink oversized pages" on the left by default was active which results in scaling down to 97%, see the right side.

If the same happens in your Adobe Reader installation, select "Actual Size" or "Custom Scale: 100%" instead.